# QGIS escape/cancel

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Unlike many GIS software QGIS doesn't seems to react to pressing the esc button! If I use the information button but accidentally click on a layer that has many features and want to stop the process, the escape button doesn't work and QGIS keeps whirring away trying to identify all the objects - there doesn't seem to be any way other than crashing it out which is not ideal in a business environment. You should be able to stop this without recourse to crashing QGIS.
Is there anyway of escaping a process?

Comment: This lacks a lot of relevant details. I suspect you're talking about the [`identify tool`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=identifi#identify)? Please provide the settings you're using on the tool, as well as the number of features on the layer, the number of attributes, and the number of features you're trying to ID with the click (determined by zoom level & feature size).

Comment: Erik - yes it is the identify tool but all the other stuff is totally irrelevant to the comment and question - it doesn't matter how many features there are or what the dataset is - it is not about that tool, that was just an example of what I was using! I'm asking if there is a way to stop a process executing mid-flow. MapInfo for example has the ability to press escape and all processing stops immediately.

Comment: So, you're presenting an example and then say "it's irrelevant", when asked for details which could help improved the performance for said example. Why post the example in the first place?

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371333/cancel-running-algorithm-in-qgis